# Spring web service is returning response locally but after deployment to another server no response is coming

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, spring-ws

I created a spring web service. Here is my xsd(s) that are using

LmsApiTypes.xsd:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com" 
xmlns="http://types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:element name="Address" type="Address"/>  
    <xsd:complexType name="Address">  
        <xsd:sequence>  
            <xsd:element name="StreetAddress" type="xsd:string" nillable="false" />
            <xsd:element name="City" type="xsd:string" nillable="false" />
            <xsd:element name="State" type="xsd:string" nillable="false" />
            <xsd:element name="ZipCode" type="xsd:string" nillable="false" />
            <xsd:element name="Country" type="xsd:string" nillable="false" />
        </xsd:sequence>  
    </xsd:complexType>
    .....
    ....
    <xsd:element name="TransactionResultType" type="TransactionResultType"/>
    <xsd:simpleType name="TransactionResultType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="Success"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="Failure"/>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

LmsApiServiceOperations.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="http://com/softech/vu360/lms/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations" 
xmlns="http://com/softech/vu360/lms/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations"  
xmlns:lmsApiTypes="http://types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://types.lmsapi.message.webservice.lms.vu360.softech.com" schemaLocation="LmsApiTypes.xsd"/> 

    <xsd:element name="CreateTrainingPlanRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="TrainingPlans" type="lmsApiTypes:TrainingPlans" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="customerCode" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="CreateTrainingPlanResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="ResponseTrainingPlans" type="lmsApiTypes:ResponseTrainingPlans" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" nillable="false" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="transactionResult" type="lmsApiTypes:TransactionResultType" use="required"/>
            <xsd:attribute name="transactionResultMessage" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Here is my web.xml file

```
....
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>99</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-ws</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

Here is my spring-ws-servlet.xml file

```
<!-- url to open for WSDL ___ http://localhost:8080/lms//service/lms-api/lmsAPI.wsdl -->
<bean id="lmsAPI" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition" lazy-init="true">  
    <property name="schemaCollection">  
        <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">  
            <property name="inline" value="true" />  
            <property name="xsds">  
                <list>  
                    <value>/WEB-INF/xsd/LmsApiServiceOperations.xsd</value>  
                </list>  
            </property>  
        </bean>  
    </property>  
    <property name="portTypeName" value="lmsApi"/>
    <!--   
    <property name="serviceName" value="AccountDetailsServices" />  -->
    <property name="locationUri" value="/service/lms-api/"/>  
</bean>

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <!-- LMS API Service operations -->         
             <value>com.softech.vu360.lms.webservice.message.lmsapi.serviceoperations.CreateTrainingPlanRequest</value>                 
             <value>com.softech.vu360.lms.webservice.message.lmsapi.serviceoperations.CreateTrainingPlanResponse</value> 
            ....
             <!-- LMS API types -->

              <value>com.softech.vu360.lms.webservice.message.lmsapi.types.Address</value>
           </list>
    </property>
    <property name="schemas">
        <list>
          ... 
            <value>/WEB-INF/xsd/LmsApiServiceOperations.xsd</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

here is my end point

```
@Endpoint
public class LMSAPIWSImpl implements LMSAPIWS {
    private static final String TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://com/softech/vu360/lms/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations";
    private static final String CREATE_TRAININGPLAN_EVENT = "CreateTrainingPlanRequest";

    @Override
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = CREATE_TRAININGPLAN_EVENT, namespace = TARGET_NAMESPACE)
    public CreateTrainingPlanResponse createTrainingPlan(CreateTrainingPlanRequest request) {
      ....
      }
}
```

The problem is when i deploy service locally and test the webservice using SoapUi then i get the response, but when i deploy it on another server then no response is return. Please help, why i am getting no response from another server, while locally everything is working fine.

Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing an error? Or a timeout? Is the remote server accessible on the port number the application is deployed on?

Comment: No no error. It give me this raw data `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Mon, 09 Dec 2013 14:40:10 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
` On local everything is working fine ..

Comment: But i am calling it on https. Does it make any difference ?